# Is everything taking place in the world simply Ishwara's leela? A mere sport? What does the scriptures have to say?

Tags: scripture, smriti, sruti, leela, ishwara

I'm looking for scriptural verses from Sruti or Smriti (and **NOT** the claims of yogis and saints) where it is mentioned that all our experiences in this world such as happiness, suffering, grief etc. are nothing but Ishwara's leela?

No offence to the saints. I have deep respect for them but right now I'm in search of verses from Vedas, Upanishads, Puranas or from other Sruti and Smriti texts.

Many years ago, as I was browsing the internet I came across a web article that had conversations between Ramakrishna Paramahamsa and Mahendranath Gupta. The latter was better known as M or Master Moshai during his time.

These conversations took place when M recently lost his wife and so he was questioning Ramakrishna on topics like suffering. I don't remember his exact question but he asked something like "why is there so much suffering in the world?" or "why did his wife left him so soon?" or "why did God do this to him?"

Again, i'm sorry for not remembering his exact question since i went through the article a long time ago but I do remember Ramakrishna's reply.

He said
"all this is Ishwara's leela".

I wish to know if the same thing is mentioned in Sruti or Smriti scriptures as well, that whatever goes on in this world whether good, bad or neutral, are all Ishwara's leela?

Thank you.